# Ruby Gem Guard on Ubuntu, no 'guard' command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, rubygems, rspec, guard

Trying to install Guard on my ubuntu machine, but when I try to run it from command line I get this error:

```
No command 'guard' found, did you mean:
 Command 'guards' from package 'quilt' (main)
guard: command not found
```

All my other gems work fine from command line, so the gems path is good.  gem list shows guard (0.5.1) and guard-rspec (0.4.0).  I also installed libnotify and rb-inotify

What am I missing?

Comment: What gem did you install in your Gemfile? Some `guard-*` gems lack a dependency on `guard`, for example `guard-test`. You have to specify them both.

Comment: My apologies, this question was asked 6 years ago and I have no recollection now.  Judging by the answer I accepted, the problem was resolved by using RVM instead of the "out of the box" ubuntu ruby stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had no issues setting up the guard-rspec gem on Ubuntu. I assume you do not use sudo to install your gems. This would cause a problem.

**Update in response to comment regarding installing gems using sudo.**

If you sudo gem install - which you really should not do - then your terminal will have no access to the gem. If this is the case then uninstall all your gems then re-install using bundle, rvm or whatever without the sudo command. On Ubuntu when you use the command shell you are not logged in as root.

I highly recommend you use rvm to manage your gems. They will be installed to your home folder
See here for more details https://rvm.io
**End of update**

If your really have to sudo install your gems then you will have to sudo run them as well and as your app is not run under a sudo shell this will cause issues.

I suggest you check the name of your gem in your gemfile.rb it should be
gem "guard-rspec"

define this in your test group and make sure you run bundle install.

One major benefit of using Ubuntu is that you can also use the libnotify and libnotify-rails gems which work beautifully well. You will see a message about this after you have run guard rspec:install and then guard for the first time. Check the messages carefully you will be very pleasantly surprised.

The libnotify gems give you a popup window that tells you the state of your tests every time they run. It's totally awesome

Comment: I sudo install all my gems.  gem "guard-rspec" is in the gemfile. Am on Ubuntu 11.04, 2 different machines have given me the same error.

Comment: I have adjusted my answer accordingly. Don't use sudo :)

Answer (score 10):

Try `bundle exec guard [rest of command]`.

Comment: This was the fix for me--not sure why I didn't think of it. I'm using Fedora 17 with RBENV and I just added 'guard-rspec' to my Gemfile. I'll probably build an alias in my bash profile so I don't have to prefix 'bundle exec' anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
gem install guard
```

or add

```
gem 'guard', '~> 2.14', '>= 2.14.1'
```

to the Gemfile.
Run

```
bundle install
```

See [Guard docs](https://rubygems.org/gems/guard)